Polar axis, theta ticks getting misplaced
So I'm trying to compile some code in a large document to give me this graph of a polar function
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{polaraxis}[]
    \addplot[domain=0:360,samples=300, color=red] {1 + 2*cos(x)};
  \end{polaraxis}

  \end{tikzpicture}


and for some reason it works when I put it in a blank document with packages
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

but not in my larger document. Here is what it
.
I'm not sure what to do, especially since my compiler isn't giving me any errors, but when I delete
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,    
                    axis line style={<->,color=black},
                    xlabel={$x$}}},

it seems to get fixed. I think it has something to do with the xlabel.
I've been trying to figure it out but haven't made much progress after a good 2 hours so I'd appreciate any help.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You most probably have some settings or packages in your "larger document" causing the problem. No one here has any way to know and your question is thereby completely unanswerable. Please do the work yourself - e.g. by making a copy of your "larger document" and start removing things until you know what is happening. If you do not delete or edit your question, it will probably be closed.

Hi guys, I took your advice and edited the question. I found what code was causing the problem but I'm still not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

This code are at polaraxis superfluous. You coordinate definitions has sense at not polar diagrams.

How can I change my coordinate system then? I can't delete what I have before since that relates to another graph, but can I change it later so I can have the polar graph?

The first of all, please  provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) a small but complete, compilable code, which reproduce your diagram and which we can test as it is. What you like to change in axis? A style of lines, size of fonts? This still can be done as at other pgfplots diagrams.

Sure, so the code I included
\begin{document}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[]
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=300, color=red] {1 + 2*cos(x)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
works

Please create a MWE showing your problem. Edit your question to include this code. Giving error filled code in the comments is not helpful. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that
